# Python- Pandas - date time index type error

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, typeerror, python-datetime

I want to calculate the number of days between the a two particular dates. I am using pandas in the code. Also I am using a Python 3.4.2 version with anaconda 2.1 in mac OS-X Yosemite.
I get the following error

```
/Users/Hari/Documents/EdenWorks/crop_planning.py in plant_crops(self, dates, crop)
overflow = crop.copy()
# Get date offsets and plant size
date_offsets = (dates - self.dates[0]).days
plant_width = crop['Plant width']
plant_length = crop['Plant length']
```

/Users/Hari/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/tseries/index.py in **sub**(self, other)

```
  return self.shift(-other)
  else:  # pragma: no cover
  raise TypeError(other)
```

TypeError: 2014-12-02 00:00:00

both the variable dates and self.dates[0] are DateTimeindex. 
Could you help me with this?

Comment: Looking at the [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) it looks like DateTimeIndex is an ndarray. You need to convert the DateTimeIndex into a format that can be subtracted.

Comment: Also, it looks like you've got your code mixed up with your error message ... take some time to make all that clearer.

Comment: Thank you BarFooBar. I tried to typecase the variable to int type but still i get the same error.
Ajean: Sorry. I have edited the question and tried to make it a bit more clear